# How to extract the word features in trained model of MultinomialNB Pipeline in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

```
# Note: The runnable code example is at the end of this question ####
# Assume X_train contains cleaned sentence text as input data. Y_train are class labels. 
# parameters stores the parameter to be tried by GridSearchCV

text_clf_Pipline_MultinomialNB = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                                           ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                                           ('clf', MultinomialNB()),                     
                                          ])
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf_Pipline_MultinomialNB, parameters, n_jobs=-1)   
gs_classifier = gs_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now I can get the feature_log_prob_ from the gs_classifier based on [sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html). Here is an example.

My question is how to get the word correspond to each log probability? 
The CountVectorizer() and TfidfTransformer() both did feature selection. 
Where do the GridSearchCV Object stores the selected word/ngram features? How to get match them back to the probabilities?

I have inspected the members of gs_classifier, while have not found the selected features. Thanks.

The following is a runnable example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from inspect import getmembers

X_train = ['qwe rtyuiop', 'asd fghj kl', 'zx cv bnm', 'qw erty ui op', 'as df ghj kl', 'zxc vb nm', 'qwe rt yu iop', 'asdfg hj kl', 'zx cvb nm',
          'qwe rt yui op', 'asd fghj kl', 'zx cvb nm', 'qwer tyui op', 'asd fg hjk l', 'zx cv b nm', 'qw ert yu iop', 'as df gh jkl', 'zx cvb nm',
           'qwe rty uiop', 'asd fghj kl', 'zx cvbnm', 'qw erty ui op', 'as df ghj kl', 'zxc vb nm', 'qwe rtyu iop', 'as dfg hj kl', 'zx cvb nm',
          'qwe rt yui op', 'asd fg hj kl', 'zx cvb nm', 'qwer tyuiop', 'asd fghjk l', 'zx cv b nm', 'qw ert yu iop', 'as df gh jkl', 'zx cvb nm']    

y_train = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '1', '3', '1', '2', '3',
          '1', '2', '3', '1', '4', '1', '2', '2', '4', 
          '1', '2', '3', '1', '1', '3', '1', '2', '3',
          '1', '2', '3', '1', '4', '1', '2', '2', '4']    


parameters = {  
                'clf__alpha': (1e-1, 1e-2),
                 'vect__ngram_range': [(1,2),(1,3)],
                 'vect__max_df': (0.9, 0.98)
            }

text_clf_Pipline_MultinomialNB = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                                           ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                                           ('clf', MultinomialNB()),                     
                                          ])
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf_Pipline_MultinomialNB, parameters, n_jobs=-1)   

gs_classifier = gs_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

nbclf = getmembers(gs_classifier.best_estimator_)[2][1]['named_steps']['clf']
nbclf.feature_log_prob_
```

Then the question are: How can I get the word feature list in trained model corresponds to the log probabilities? Also, for example, which probability in _log_prob_ output corresponds to the word 'qwe' for class '1'?

---

Edit after get the answer:
Andreas's answer works:

```
gs_classifier.best_estimator_.named_steps['vect'].get_feature_names()
```

Similar to this, there is a better way to index into the GridSearchCV to get the trained classifier

```
nbclf = gs_classifier.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need `getmembers`?
To get the feature names corresponding to `feature_log_prob_`:

`gs_classifier.best_estimator_.named_steps['vect'].get_feature_names()`

Comment: Thanks! Your answer not only solved my problem but also give me the elegant/correct way to index into GridSearchCV.